# Highlight only cells in PrimeFaces dataTable that change value

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, cell

I have a PrimeFaces `dataTable` that I fill by a `load` method in server that uses a variable `ArrayList` as usual.
I have developed a `poll` that every X minutes calls the same `load` method and refreshes all data in the `dataTable`.
I would like to highlight all cells in the tables that effectively are modified in value.

For example if a cell change his value from 5 to 6 must be highlighted instead if a value cell is 5 and after update remain 5 not must be highlighted.

Could someone tell me what kind of approach is better to do this?

Comment: You know how to give cells a colour with css, right? Then simply server side in your model, set a 'changed' flag on each value that is changed and use that flag to change/set the colour when updating the datatable.

Comment: ok, but I can't change the data model. Other ideas?

Comment: Then wrap the datamodel in a 'myCustomDataModel'... (you DO have access/control over the lazyDataModel implementation where the 'load' method resides do you?)

Comment: yes i do. thanks for the answer, but in your opinion could exist a client solution? using only  javascript / jquery or some trick with primefaces?

Comment: Sure, you can fully override the javascript that updates the client side html. You can parse the response from the server and do a cell for cell comparison with what exists on the client. Providing a solution for you in that direction is however beyond the scope of what StackOverflow is for and way beyond the (free/spare) time I have and want to spend on support in Stackoverflow.